# What is lower_bound(B,B+N,goal) - B in C++

Tags: c++

When I see some [code](https://github.com/E869120/kyopro_educational_90/blob/main/sol/076.cpp) I found `lower_bound` function which execute binary search. it is used like following.

```
int pos1 = lower_bound(B, B + N, goal) - B;
```

I understand that `lower_bound` returns iterators , but what is the role of `-B` in this sample.

I totally confused about this, if someone has opinion will you please let me know
Thanks

Comment: It calculates the distance between the returned iterator and the start of the array (in a not exactly clean fashion). Seems rather pointless in the code, since it is only used as an index into the array

Comment: Please insert the code in the post and describe, what the code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it calculates the difference between the iterator returned from `lower_bound` and `B`. `pos` can then be used as index to `B`: `B[pos]`.

A cleaner way to get the distance between two iterators is using [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
 auto it = std::lower_bound(....);
 auto offset = std::distance(B,it);
```

However, there is no reason to switch back and forth between iterators and indices, unless you really need the index. For accessing elements in the container one can simply use the returned iterator: `*it == B[pos]`.